# DataGridView not updating when bound items are changed?

Tags: .net, data-binding

I have a DataGridView which I am binding like so:

```
companies = new BindingList<Company>(PersistenceManager.Instance.RetrieveAll<Company>(SessionAction.BeginAndEnd));
bindingSource.DataSource = companies;
potentialInvestorDataGridView.DataBindings.Add("DataSource", bindingSource, "PotentialInvestors");
```

The problem is when I add to the PotentialInvestors list

```
Company company = bindingSource.Current as Company;
company.PotentialInvestors.Add ( new Investor ( ) );
```

The datagrid does not get updated with a new row. I have tried to calling

```
bindingSource.ResetCurrentItem();
potentialInvestorDataGridView.EndEdit();
potentialInvestorDataGridView.Refresh();
```

But nothing seems to update the data grid. (If I close the dialog and reopen it the items are now displayed).

What do I need to do to have this updated properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changes will only be propogated if the underlying data source (the result of `PersistenceManager.Instance.RetrieveAll<Company>(...)`) supports the notification mechanism. I'm pretty sure that in order for it to work that `IBindingList` must be supported on the data source itself. Do you have a list of the interfaces that the data source implements?

**Edit**

You can manually invoke a `Reset` value on the `ListChanged` event (which is what the grid is watching for) by calling `ResetBindings` on the gridview. This, however, will cause the grid to refresh *all* of the data, not just what has changed.

Comment: Both my Company and Investor class support the INotifyPropertyChanged interface so they should be notifying of property updates.

Either way, I should be able to tell the datagrid to update somehow though?